# How can I pass data from express server to react views?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, socket.io

I have a simple express server with a connection to a orientdb database.
I need to pass information from express to react views.
For example, in express I have:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Vertex.getFromClass('Post').then(
    function (posts) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'express' });
    }
  );
});
```

So, in this example, I need to have in my react index component, the `posts` variable to set the state of the componenent. (I'm using react only in the frontend, not server-side)

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Posts posts={posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I get the posts in react from express?

I found that maybe I can do an ajax request from react, but I think that that isn't the best way.

If I need to get that posts in a real time way, using socket.io for example, what are the differences?

PD: In express I have the possibility to use some template engine like handlebars or hogan. Can this template engines help in this topic?

Thanks!!!

Comment: There is no server side react, it can only be used in frontend

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your best option is to indeed make some kind of network request from the client. If you aim to keep the app simple and do not want a State Management library (e.g. Redux), you could do something like

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/') // or whatever URL you want
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((posts) => this.setState({
        posts: posts,
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Posts posts={this.state.posts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In your `response` there should be a JSON representation of the posts collection.

Also note the `render` method and accessing the `posts`.

For more on Fetch API see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (please also note that you will need a polyfill for older browsers for it).

**EDIT:** For socket.io I'd store the instance of it somewhere and pass it as a prop to the component. Then you can do something like

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.socket.on('postReceived', this.handleNewPost);
  }
  handleNewPost = (post) => {
    this.setState({
      posts: [
        ...this.state.posts,
        post,
      ],
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

The server-side part is similar, see for example [Socket.io Chat example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat).

Comment: Thanks! And if I need to do this in a real-time way, there is some function like fetch in socket.io? Or is a totally different way in real-time? What about the server, is the same

Comment: What about the server, is the same if I fetch the data real time, or there are many changes?

Comment: I don't have much experience in real-time web, but I don't think it really matters to React. All you need to do is to call `setState` whenever new data arrive (there will be some callback from socket.io). The server-side would use socket.io to push JSON to the client. It is best to find some tutorial for that, I'm sure there are plenty.