# How to loop though the data received from the server in React.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have the following route in my index.js file in my express app:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var connection = createDBConnection();

  connection.connect( );

  connection.query('SELECT tag from mytags', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log( rows );

    res.render('index', { tags : rows });

  });

});
```

In my index.ejs file i run through this data like so:

```
<% var data = tags %>
<% data.forEach( function( _e , i ) {  %>
    <div class="pretty p-default p-round p-thick">
        <input type="radio" value="<%= _e.tag %>" name="tagsradio"/>
        <div class="state p-success-o">
            <label><%= _e.tag %></label>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

The thing is right now i have moved the client to React.js and i am a bit confused as to how i would directly run though the data received form the server, without making a fetch|Ajax request ?

I do see a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40071880/4381665), but again its using fetch , is there anywhere i can directly run through the values received from the server ?

Comment: But how are you receiving data without fetch. Are you using server side rendering?

Comment: You'd have to inject the data into your HTML as global javascript variables. It's much cleaner to make an ajax request, why don't you want to?

Comment: @cEeNiKc using ejs all i have to `<% var data = tags %>` and then i can use data

Comment: Yeah I get that but when you are using react, are you using server side rendering? Do you have access to that data from the server in react without fetching it through an ajax call? Because if you are not using server side rendering then there is now way you can get data from your server without making an ajax call or through websockets.

Comment: @cEeNiKc , i see , well then i guess i will have to go with making that fetch request.

Comment: Yeah react is best at that. There are still some workarounds but server side rendering is a real headache for react especially if you are new to it